# Should there be any difference between window.localStorage.setItem and localStorage.setItem?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, google-chrome-devtools

I have a Chrome extension that works perfectly for Mac and Linux users but isn't working for Windows users. When I go into a console and set an item in localStorage it works fine, however when the user tries to use the extension, items aren't being set in localStorage via my actual code.

My current hypothesis is that using `window.localStorage` *might* make it work but I have no data to back that up.

Would anyone here be able to add color as to why that may work or not work?

Comment: It is possible that localStorage under extensions is still linked to the domain.  (I use TamperMonkey to make my Chrome extensions, which  runs differently... but you could look at the TamperMonkey source to see how they do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the global context of the extension is *not* the `window` object contrary to normal Javascipt apps, then you will need to reference it.

You can also cache it to save some tree-walking:

```
if (typeof localStorage === 'undefined' && window.localStorage)
    localStorage = window.localStorage;
```

Now you should be able to use the same code without prefixing.

(I believe there is a separate but similar storage  mechanism for Chrome extensions).

This may be of interest too:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html

Comment: `if (!localStorage` will fail if it hasn't been defined